# Pass the value of external variables in a tagged template

Tags: javascript

`tag` is a function that accepts a template string:

```js
function tag(strings) {
    console.log(strings.raw);
}

tag`Output something`
```

It works fine. Now the problem is, I have an external variable and I want to pass the value of the variable to the template string, something like this:

```js
function tag(strings) {
    console.log(strings.raw);
}

const key = "a"
tag`The value of key: ${key}` // I need it to output "The value of key: a", but the actual output is "The value of key: "
```

It doesn't work as expected because javascript thinks `key` is one of `tag`'s parameters. How to solve this problem?

Comment: It *is* one of `tag`’s parameters. That’s how tagged template literals work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates

Answer (score 0):

You need to have another parameter that accepts the key value.

```
function tag( strings, key ) {
    console.log(strings[0] + key);
}

const key = "a"
tag`The value of key: ${key}`
```